# Enum value internationalization at Wicket

Tags: java, internationalization, wicket

I have an enum FooBar at class Clazz with falues FOO and BAR like this:

```
class Clazz {
    enum FooBar{
        FOO,
        BAR
    }
}
```

I now would like to use wicket `getString()` method to localize the values `FOO` and `BAR`. The best I can do is to define at i18n file

```
 Clazz.FooBar.FOO=foo
 Clazz.FooBar.BAR=bar
```

and I get values with this code

```
 fooBar = FooBar.FOO;
 getString("Clazz.FooBar." + fooBar.name());
```

I have heard that this could be achieved without `Clazz.FooBar` addition to the i18n query string, but the method to be called would be different. How to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't like my answer? I think it directly answers your question if I haven't misunderstood anything.

Comment: Actually, I somehow missed the point of your answer while looking an idea closer to my predefined view of how this should be working. Your answer is code wise the nicest. I'll accept it 'cause then I have to make less code changes. (Adding stuff to every enum is not a good idea although given in so many answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this method in your base page/panel:

```
public String getString(Enum<?> value) {
    Class<?> enclosingClass = value.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
    String key = (enclosingClass == null ? "" : enclosingClass.getSimpleName() + ".")
            + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + value.name();
    return getString(key);
}
```

Then you can simply call it with

```
getString(Clazz.FooBar.FOO);
```

and it will return what you defined in the property file.

Answer (score 1):

I will not advice you to directly store enum constant names in properties file the reason is simple two different enums can hold same name.

Below is the code I have come up with

```
class Clazz {
enum FooBar {
    //StrId are keys from property file e.g. below
    FOO("com.abc.classz.foobar.FOO"), BAR("com.abc.classz.foobar.BAR");

    private final String strId;

    private FooBar(String id) {
        this.strId = id;
    }

    // toString can also be used here I am just keen on having seperate
    // method
    public String getName() {
        //Load Value for strId from properties file
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

This will keep your enum and your i18n purpose separate and clear.

Answer (score 0):

See below sample Enum class. You may want to customize it more depending on your needs.

```
    public enum FooBar {

    foo("foobar.foo"),
    bar("foobar.bar");

    private String key;

    ErrorCodeEnum(final String key) {
        this.key = key;     
    }



    public String toString() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

then you can make the toString method to return key directly so you can use

```
 getString(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR1);
```

or you can override the toString method directly like below

```
 public enum FooBar {

    foo, bar;

     public String toString(){
        return getClass().getName()+"."+name();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for an rapid answer! Still I'm waiting something that is more specific to wicket and that I wouldn't need to touch enum classes. Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define

```
FOO=foo
BAR=bar
```

in your properties and access it by

```
getString(fooBar.name());
```

or am I missing some point?

Comment: If e.g. two enums have that FOO or BAR in both of them, it would be nicer to have the whole path in there. It works with full method path (org.my.company.and.what.ever.else.Clazz.FooBar.FOO=foo) and then getting `getString(fooBar.getCanonicalName);` but I don't like so long names at props file. That's why I want that three part one.

Comment: In that case you could create an `IStringResourceLoader` that mapps `foobar.getCannonicalName()` to `Clazz.FooBar.FOO`...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something called [`EnumChoiceRenderer`](http://blog.armstrongconsulting.com/?p=163). The main idea is to give a EnumChoiceRenderer for e.g. DropDownChoise element and you're able to give parameters of the kind I was proposing in my question. Ok, in this solution you're able to give only

```
     FooBar.BAR=bar
     FooBar.FOO=foo
```

in your resource file but this is the closest I could find when I investigated this more with my spare time.

*PS. Click the EnumChoiseRenderer in the beginning of this answer to see the article of this solution.*